# Updating nested Area chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my application I have multiple checkboxes which contain the name of the product. User can select one or multiple products. When the user selects a particular product an area graph is drawn based on the number of products sold on certain days.

- If multiple products are selected a stacked area graph is drawn.
- If no product is selected no graph is shown just a message to select atleast one product is shown.

Code: 
This is called once when the graph is initialized.

```
function initialiseChart(element){
  var bRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 20};
  var height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  var width = bRect.width - margin.left - margin.right;

  var localChart = d3.select(element).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

}
```

This is called when a user selects or de-selects a checkbox, selectedIds contain all the product ids which are selected. If all are deselected then selectedIds array is an empty array.

```
function updateChart(selectedIds,localChart,height,width){

  var z = d3.scale.category20c();
  var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear() .range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(12);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

  var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .offset("zero")
      .values(function(d) {
        return d.values;
      })
      .x(function(d,i) {  return d.date; })
      .y(function(d,i) {  return d.counts; });

  var nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.pid; });

  var area = d3.svg.area()
      .interpolate("cardinal")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y0(function(d) {
        return y(d.y0);
      })
      .y1(function(d) {
        return y(d.y0 + d.y);
      });


  var data = assignDefaultValues(selectedIds); //returns the data for selectedIds

  var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

  localChart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  localChart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

   localChart.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers)
      .exit().remove();

  localChart.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "layers")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });

}
```

Problem:

Whenever I select or deselect the checkbox the selectedIds array has content as expected, as in empty if all are selected or ids of one or more products which are selected.

But the axes are redrawn, also the first graph that is plotted doesnt go away even if its deselected.

What is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: A complete fiddle would help.

Comment: I found out that the exit().remove() method doesnt gets called when the selectedIds are updated and update method is called. But still couldnt guess the reason though..